# Excel value distribution in various columns in limits

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to distribute a number (say in Column A) in to four different columns (Column B, C, D, E) in Excel so that (i) the sum of values shown in columns B, C, D, E is equal to the value of Column A. (ii) The values shall only be whole numbers (iii) Columns B, C, D, E have maximum limit of 10, 10, 5 and 5 respectively. That is the values generated in these columns should be with in these maximum limit values.

Example:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: where are your attempts? What doesn't work with them?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a *recursive* `LAMBDA`:

With the active cell within the worksheet somewhere in row 1, go to *Name Manager* and define *MyLambda* as:

`=LAMBDA(ξ,LET(ζ,RANDARRAY(,4,,{10,10,5,5},1),IF(SUM(ζ)=$A1,ζ,MyLambda(ξ))))`

Back in the worksheet, in `B1` enter the formula:

`=MyLambda(1)`